# Why does the equals() method return false when the two objects are identical?

Tags: java, class, object, equals, equality

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o1 = new Object();
        Object o2 = new Object();
        System.out.print((o1 == o2) + " " + (o1.equals(o2)));
    }
}
```

I read this in a different answer:

> The `==` operator tests whether two variables have the same references (aka pointer to a memory address).
>
> Whereas the `equals()` method tests whether two variables refer to objects that have the same state (values).

Here, since  `o1` and `o2` reference two different objects, I get why  `==` returns false.

But both the objects are created using the default constructor of the `Object` class, and therefore have same values. Why does the `equals()` method return false?

Comment: Maybe because one has to **override the `equals` method?

Comment: See [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) "The equals method for class `Object` implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns true if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value true)." If you want something less discriminating, you have to `override` equals and alter the behaviour.

Comment: `Object.equals` uses `==` as comparator.

Comment: Objects are only considered equal if they have the same reference. That was just a design decision because otherwise every object would be equal which would create a whole bunch of problems.

Answer (score 6):

The implementation of `equals()` supplied by `java.lang.Object` is **defined** to return `false`, unless the references refer to the same object, in which case it returns `true`.

This is by design (the method mimics the behaviour of `==`) and encourages programmers to implement their own version of `equals()`, if appropriate, for their `class`. For example, see `java.lang.String#equals` which compares the *contents* if another `String` is passed as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

You have to write your own `equals` method that overrides the `equals` method of `class Object` because that method returns `true` if `this` object is the same as the object in the argument and `false` otherwise.

The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any **non-null** reference values `x` and `y`, this method returns `true` if and only if `x` and `y` refer to the same object (`x == y` has the value `true`). (for more information, read Javadoc)

Answer (score 2):

All Java objects inherit from the `Object` class.  The methods of `Object`, therefore, are available to all Java objects.  One of these methods is `equals()`.

The implementation for `equals()` in class `Object`, by default, is identical to the `==` operator.

If a programmer wishes to use `equals()` to test objects for value equality, he must override `equals()` and provide his own implementation (that should comply with the general contract for `equals()`; refer to the Javadoc).

Comment: Your second paragraph in particular is nicely put. Have an upvote!